# Can't redirect http requests to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

Hello I want to redirect my http requests to https. I add some code to .htaccess but still I can access to my website with http. What's wrong and what should I do?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteOptions inherit
Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Comment: I've edited the content you posted to remove references to your websites.  It is better to use dummy content when posting instead of real site names where possible

Comment: tnx sry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, could you please try following htaccess rues set. Since you are using inherit option for Rules, so in case you want to apply https in all URLs then better put your htpps rules in your BASE(very first level folder wise) htaccess file and we need not to put them here, if you want to only apply https to URLs which are covered here then use following style rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteOptions inherit
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
  
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Comment: @Mj Ebrahimzadeh, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?

Comment: it worked tnx but what should I do to enable it even for sub domains? like webmail.example.com

Answer (score 1):

The following code redirect any URL of your domain to HTTPS version and set HSTS:

```
#Redirect HTTP a HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#HSTS
<if "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</if>
```